# error: expression must have pointer-to-object type

Tags: c++

I tried to design a program that will return the original 32bit value `w` but change the number `i` element to `1`. Here's the function I got so far. But for this part, `v[i]=1;` , it just says that for `i` expression must have pointer to object type.

```
 unsigned int setBit(unsigned int w,unsigned int i)
 {
    unsigned int v = w;
    v[i]=1;
    return v;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned int v = w;
v[i] = 1; // error, v is not an array
```

This is not correct because `v` is not an array. The solution might be using a `std::bitset` or simply shifting bits and using some bit manipulation - this would be faster.

```
unsigned int setBit(unsigned int w,unsigned int i) {
    unsigned int v = ( w |= 1 << i);
    return v;
}
```

usage:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int in = 0;
    unsigned int res = setBit(in,1); // set 1st bit in 0 to 1, results in 2
    return 0;
}
```

---

meaning of `unsigned int v = ( w |= 1 << i);`

| - [the bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)

<< - [the bitwise shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts)

`v = ( w |= 1 << i)` is the same as `v = ( w = w | 1 << i)` so it means: `v` is equal to (take `w` and `OR` it with `1` left shifted by `i`, and assign this to `w`)

[about C/C++ bit manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990/1141471)

Comment: What's the meaning of "|=" ? And the "<<" behind it. I'm really just a beginner on C++. Thanks

Comment: |= is the condensed version of | and =, meaning `w |= 1` means the same as `w = w | 1`. Just like +=.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `[]` operator is for `string/array/vector/map/...`, but not for a `unsigned int`.

For your example, you probably need to change it to `bit array` first to be able to use such way.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're interested.

```
unsigned int setBit(unsigned int w, unsigned int i)
{
  std::bitset<sizeof(unsigned int)> bitset((unsigned long long)w);
  bs.set(i, 1);
  (unsigned int)return bs.to_ulong();
}
```

Although I would still use `piotrus`' answer.